Question with many views
Does anybody know why this question has many more views than the other ones posted around the same time (almost 1000 at the time of writing, vs. 50/100 views for the questions nearby)? Is there a bug in the counter? Any key word that might have lured search engines?

Qualcuno ha un'idea del perché questa domanda ha tante più visualizzazioni delle altre inserite negli stessi giorni (quasi 1000, mentre sto scrivendo, contro le 50/100 di quelle nei paraggi)? C'è un bug nel contatore? Qualche parola chiave ha attratto i motori di ricerca?

(Mi scusate di rispondere in inglese, ma il mio italiano è molto arrugginito...)
It's not a bug. That question really has 10 times more views than most of the others on the site. Our analytics confirm that there was a spike in traffic corresponding to the date that question was asked. It's hard to tell exactly what happened, but essentially that question seems to have struck more Googlers' fancy than most other questions on the site.
It's a traffic windfall. Nice work :)

E' possibile anche che la domanda abbia in qualche modo raggiunto le "Hot Network Questions" che compaiono in tutti i siti del network. Quelle domande spesso attirano la curiosità degli utenti di altre sezioni di SE, che vengono a curiosare.
Questo sarebbe coerente con la punta di traffico corrispondente alla data di immissione della domanda notato da Abby T. Miller, magari in un momento in cui non ne venivano inserite molte altre nel sito (dovrei controllare, ma non so se sia possibile e non mi attira l'idea di spenderci del tempo, ma se il dato è disponibile da qualche parte probabilmente qualcuno meglio informato di me ti saprà dire come accedervi).

Potrebbe essere probabilmente causato dal fatto che 'bravo' è una parola famosa al maschile, è un errore fatto in molte parti del mondo, e quindi potrebbe potenzialmente attirare numerose visite. Mi chiedo se possediamo statistiche delle visualizzazioni in termini geografici.
Provate a dire ad una persona che non parla italiano che 'bravo' indirizzato ad una donna è errato, o che 'salami' è solo per più di un salame, mentre un 'panino con il salame' non può essere chiamato 'bread with salami'... la sorpresa è garantita.
